# Using too many exits a good practise?

Tags: php

Say I have made an ajax request to a `php` file. when the result is success or something other. I do not need my server to go through the rest of the code. So I was thinking to use `exit` function but having too many `exits` a good practise ? I am not sure.

```
  if(some condition) exit("success");
  else if(some condition) exit("fail");
 // after some 3 lines or so
 if(fail) exit("error");
```

Using too many exit functions in PHP is a good or bad practice. Could anyone tell me are there any restrictions on using `exit` function? I have been told that you cannot use too many `return` statements in a function and I was thinking may be even `exit` must not be used more frequently. Using too many `exit` functions a wrong way of doing things?

### Update

When it has satisfied the given requirement, there is no need for further execution of code. I don't want my server to go down and meet the end I could simply exit. It makes faster I guess?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it. but you might want to put in some extra data that'd be useful to your JS code to explain to the user why something failed. e.g. "Sorry, but you didn't meet 'some condition'" rather than just "fail".

Comment: It's not "bad practice" but could be a sign of poor design. I wouldn't say it's "good practice" either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to have multiple exit messages, drawing a correlation between having multiple return statements in a method.

If you did not have multiple exit messages, I think your code would be kind of ugly:

```
$retCondition = "success";

if(!some condition) {
  if(some condition 2) $retCondition = "fail";
  else {
    ..Your code
  }
}
exit($retCondition);
```

This is kind of a php solution, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

To me it is wrong practice. If possible one entry point and one exit point - it's irrelevant what language it is. I care my time and such approach simply help reading, maintaining and debugging code.

**EDIT**

To summary my point here (or follow the comments): this is not black/white case, so you never should be really 100% strict, but I tend to avoid early returns if I find this causing readability loss and this is a sufficient reason for me but also I sometimes agree to do the opposite if the code whould simply look like xmas tree with all nested `if()/else` blocks.

Comment: Does this mean you are against the approach of early `return`s too?

Comment: Multiple returns are ok so long as they are not hidden in code. Multiple exits is bad in my opinion

Comment: In general - yes, i am against. I can accept early exit if method is complicated and condition is obvious - then early exit() instead of another code block is fine for me as kind of exception (but it is only allowed because it is clearly visible). But I do not accept `exit()` or `return()` in middle of the code - you can easy overlook that so it's basically bad thing. And since I do not like having to much exceptions to the rules (so they stay simple and clear), then the one-enter-one-exit is what I try to have whenever possible

Comment: Disagree, if multiple exits make the code more readable then it is a good thing.

Comment: If multiple exists exist in a large code base its a nightmare to follow it

Comment: @PeteBelford This is basically rare case. If you need to have many exists then it usually means it's time to refactor that method

Comment: If early returns in a method become a readability problem your methods are probably doing waaay to much

Comment: @PeeHaa not sure to whom you talk to now, but for me `early return` is early when it is just a few lines of code away from method start.

Comment: That makes me wonder how large your methods are :)

Comment: that's irrelevant really. if method is 3 lines long ten you can exit at any moment (but it usually makes no sense). but for normal, live code most methods are often longer. There's no point of sacrificing  readability in favour of "saving" one or two brackets

Comment: Early returns prevent further execution within the scope of a single function but an early exit kills the whole application. Comparison of the two isn't really fair.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  I would disagree, and would assert that it is far more common to have multiple return statements in a method.  In the most basic case if you have a String parameter to a method.  How do you handle a null, a blank, or an empty?  All could be different.

Comment: if you got conditional blocks then you execute nothing anyway. The only difference is you got one code block less if you return earlier.

Comment: @PeteBelford depends on the method. you got `else`. Anyway this is not black/white case so you never should be really 100% strict. But I tend to avoid early returns if I find this causing readability loss

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `Exception` and only use `exit` if `redirecting` using `headers`

```
try {

    if (! $conditionA) {
        throw new Exception(" Fail ConditionA");
    }

    if (! $conditionB) {
        throw new Exception(" Fail ConditionB");
    }

    header("Location: xxx");
    exit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using exit is a bad practice. It should only be used if crucial code fails for example:

```
<?php defined('FOO') or exit('Foo not set');?>
<?php mysql_connect('usr','pwd','host') or exit('could not connect');?>
```

For normal circumstances for example the 'if' statement:

```
if (condition) {
  echo 'Hello';
} else {
  callSomeFunction();
}
```

Let's say you have a fooBar function:

```
function fooBar () {
   if (condition) {
     return 'Hello';
   } else {
     return FALSE; // If you use return the function 'fooBar' stops at that point
     echo 'Hello?'; // This is not executed because we already returned.
   }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: "It should only be used if crucial code fails" `header('Location: http://example.com'); exit;` <- nothing crucial just failed

Comment: That is one place where you should use exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a true object oriented style it should be structured similar to the following

```
function foo($x){

    if (!is_int($x)) throw new Exception('foo needs an int argument');

    return $x *2

}
```

Now there is only one return and when you call the method you use

```
$variable = 0;

try{

    $variable = $this->foo(2.5);

}catch(Exception e){

    print_r($e)
}
```

which allows you to see the problem and handle it in a controlled way.

it follows the flow chart way of having 1 "start" and 1 "end" but allows very verbose messages to be displayed etc

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't cause any problem, but it's nice to have just one exit point. It may make debugging easier. You can do it this way:

```
if(some condition) $error_msg = "success";
else if(some condition) $error_msg = "fail";

// after some 3 lines or so
if(fail) $error_msg = "error";

if($error_msg != '') exit($error_msg);
```